# Haskell defined a simple parser to recognise symbols. failure in some testing

Tags: parsing, haskell, monads

I was currently reading "write yourself a scheme in 48 hours", and in the chapter 2 it defines a simple parser 'symbol' to recognise symbols and then define a function 'readExpr' to call the parser.

```
module Main where

import System.Environment
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec hiding (spaces)

main :: IO ()
main = do args <- getArgs
          putStrLn (readExpr (args !! 0))

symbol :: Parser Char
symbol = oneOf "!$%&|*+-/:<=?>@^_~#"

readExpr :: String -> String
readExpr input = case parse symbol "lisp" input of
    Left err -> "Not Found" ++ show err
    Right val -> "Found value" ++ show val
```

However when I try some testing:

```
>>> ghc -package parsec -o hii C1.hs

>>> ./hii *
```

it says:

```
Not Found"lisp" (line 1, column 1):
unexpected "A"
```

Also, some other symbols like & or # also won't work and give an 'index too large error'. But symbols like: %,@,! etc. these works properly.
I don't understand why some symbols works while others doesn't.

In addition, if I add quote marks over that symbol:

```
./hi "#"

Found value'#'
```

Now all the symbols work ...

Can someone please explain these to me since I'm really not familiar with monad stuff?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*` is expanded to all files in current working directory. I guess if you execute `ls`, the first file name is starting with `A`.

`#` is for comments begin, so there is no args passed to `hii`. `&` brings job to backgroud.

quotes prevents shell to translate `*#!`, so try to quote every arg passed, it'll be fine.

---

1. http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html

Comment: In the first paragraph, it's better to point out that the expansion is done by the shell, and is completely unrelated to Haskell. The Haskell program never gets to see `*`, but only its expansion. Using `echo commandWithFunnyChars` sometimes also helps to see the expansion.